# Finding entries of a joint distribution table.

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-probability

> A random variable $X$ takes values in $\{0, 1, 2\}$, while another random variable $Y$ takes values in $\{−1, 1\}$.
>
> Furthermore,
>   $P(X = 1) = P(X = 2) = \frac{1}{3} = \frac{3}{4} \cdot P(Y = 1)$,
>   $P(Y = −1|X = 0) = P(Y = −1|X = 1) = P(Y = −1|X = 2).$
>
> Find the joint distribution of $(X, Y )$ and the marginal distributions.
>
> Also, compute $E[X| Y = −1]$ and $E[Y | X = 2]$.

**My solution:**

From $P(X = 1) = P(X = 2) = \frac{1}{3} = \frac{3}{4} \cdot P(Y = 1)$ we obtain,

$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
  X\overset{\LARGE\setminus}{\phantom{.}}\overset{\Large Y}{\phantom{l}} 
    & -1 & 1 & \text{Sum} \\  \hline
  0 & ? & ? &  ? \\  \hline
  1 & ? & ? & \frac{1}{3}  \\  \hline
  2 & ? & ? & \frac{1}{3}            \\  \hline
\text{Sum} & ? & \frac{4}{9}  &   1  \\  \hline
\end{array}
$
$\Rightarrow$
$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
  X\overset{\LARGE\setminus}{\phantom{.}}\overset{\Large Y}{\phantom{l}} 
    & -1 & 1 & \text{Sum} \\  \hline
  0 & ? & ? &  \frac{1}{3}  \\  \hline
  1 & ? & ? & \frac{1}{3}  \\  \hline
  2 & ? & ? & \frac{1}{3}            \\  \hline
\text{Sum} & \frac{5}{9} & \frac{4}{9}  &   1  \\  \hline
\end{array}
$

If $P(Y = −1|X = 0) = P(Y = −1|X = 1) = P(Y = −1|X = 2)$ then,

$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
  X\overset{\LARGE\setminus}{\phantom{.}}\overset{\Large Y}{\phantom{l}} 
    & -1 & 1 & \text{Sum} \\  \hline
  0 & a & ? &  \frac{1}{3}  \\  \hline
  1 & a & ? & \frac{1}{3}  \\  \hline
  2 & a & ? & \frac{1}{3}            \\  \hline
\text{Sum} & \frac{5}{9} & \frac{4}{9}  &   1  \\  \hline
\end{array}
$

We have $3a = \frac{5}{9} \Rightarrow a = \frac{5}{27}$.

So, we obtain,

$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
  X\overset{\LARGE\setminus}{\phantom{.}}\overset{\Large Y}{\phantom{l}} 
    & -1 & 1 & \text{Sum} \\  \hline
  0 & \frac{5}{27} & ? &  \frac{1}{3} \\  \hline
  1 & \frac{5}{27} & ? & \frac{1}{3}  \\  \hline
  2 & \frac{5}{27} & ? & \frac{1}{3}            \\  \hline
\text{Sum} & \frac{5}{9} & \frac{4}{9}  &   1  \\  \hline
\end{array}
$

From subtraction with marginal probabilities, we obtain,

$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
  X\overset{\LARGE\setminus}{\phantom{.}}\overset{\Large Y}{\phantom{l}} 
    & -1 & 1 & \text{Sum} \\  \hline
  0 & \frac{5}{27} & \frac{4}{27} &  \frac{1}{3} \\  \hline
  1 & \frac{5}{27} & \frac{4}{27}  & \frac{1}{3}  \\  \hline
  2 & \frac{5}{27} & \frac{4}{27}  & \frac{1}{3}            \\  \hline
\text{Sum} & \frac{5}{9} & \frac{4}{9}  &   1  \\  \hline
\end{array}
$

So,

$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
  X  & 0 & 1 & 2 \\  \hline
  P(X|Y=-1) & \frac{\frac{5}{27}}{\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{5}{9} & \frac{\frac{5}{27}}{\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{5}{9} &  \frac{\frac{5}{27}}{\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{5}{9} \\  \hline
\end{array}
$

$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
  Y  & -1 & 1 \\  \hline
  P(Y|X=2) & \frac{\frac{5}{27}}{\frac{5}{9}}=\frac{1}{3} & \frac{\frac{4}{27}}{\frac{4}{9}}=\frac{1}{3} \\  \hline
\end{array}
$

Comment: Note that $P(Y=-1)=\frac{5}{9}$, not $\frac{1}{3}$.  So each entry in your last table should be $\frac{\frac{5}{27}}{\frac{5}{9}}=\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: @NickPeterson, which table?

Comment: The last two tables.  Look to the denominators; as Nick pointed out: $$P(X=x\mid Y=-1)=\dfrac{P(X=x,Y=-1)}{P(Y=-1)}=\dfrac{\tfrac 5{27}}{\tfrac 59}=\dfrac 13$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp, hmm..got it.